# Flask and OpenLayers

Tags: python, flask, openlayers

I have a web application which is deployed by the means of Flask. I'm using the OpenLayers map which requests a stylesheet in the folder scriptdir/theme/default. I'm not so happy with my solution, so I hope someone can give me a hint to do it better:

```
@app.route('/theme/default/style.css')
def get_openlayers_css():
   return url_for('static', filename='jslib/theme/default/style.css')
```

The javascript console shows me this warning:

```
Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html: http://localhost:5000/theme/default/style.css
   OpenLayers.Map.OpenLayers.Class.initialize                 OpenLayers.js:424
   ...
```

The requested stylesheet is located in /static/jslib/theme/default/style.css and the OpenLayers.js file in /static/jslib. I thought about streaming the css file, but I'm new to flask and therefore I was not able to get this working.

Thanks in advance!

Greetings

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you'd better configure your map with `theme: null` [1] option, which will disable the autoloading of the css, and load it by yourself in the page.

1 - http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Map-js.html#OpenLayers.Map.theme

Answer (score 2):

OpenLayers has a weird way of locating the base URL for its resources (see [source code](https://github.com/openlayers/openlayers/blob/master/lib/OpenLayers.js#L68)). If you are using the "unpacked" version (not single-file) then `OpenLayers.js` needs to be inside a folder named `lib`, otherwise the URL auto-detect will fail.

Also, your `get_openlayers_css` function is returning a text response containing the URL; you probably wanted to write a redirect:

```
@app.route('/theme/default/style.css')
def get_openlayers_css():
   return redirect(url_for('static', filename='jslib/theme/default/style.css'))
```

Comment: Thanks, the warning disappeared by applying this, but in my opinion the solution offered by tonio is more suitable.

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behaviour. Your method `def get_openlayers_css():` returns a URL as string with default MIME type `TEXT`.

Try returning the CSS content instead of the path with `Flask.send_from_directory`.

Have a look at the [example in Flask documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.10/api/#flask.send_from_directory).